# ImportError, sklearn.linear_model

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, importerror

I haven't use sklearn library for a while now and then when i tried to use it today. I got error like this:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-5a7e677da668> in <module>()
      1 import pandas as pd
----> 2 from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
      3 from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
      4 
      5 #Opening csv files

~\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py in <module>()
     62 else:
     63     from . import __check_build
---> 64     from .base import clone
     65     from .utils._show_versions import show_versions
     66 

~\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in <module>()
     11 from scipy import sparse
     12 from .externals import six
---> 13 from .utils.fixes import signature
     14 from . import __version__
     15 

~\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py in <module>()
     11 
     12 from .murmurhash import murmurhash3_32
---> 13 from .validation import (as_float_array,
     14                          assert_all_finite,
     15                          check_random_state, column_or_1d, check_array,

~\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in <module>()
     20 
     21 from ..externals import six
---> 22 from ..utils.fixes import signature
     23 from .. import get_config as _get_config
     24 from ..exceptions import NonBLASDotWarning

~\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\fixes.py in <module>()
     81             return stats.boxcox(x, lmbda)
     82 else:
---> 83     from scipy.special import boxcox  # noqa
     84 
     85 

~\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\special\__init__.py in <module>()
    638 from .sf_error import SpecialFunctionWarning, SpecialFunctionError
    639 
--> 640 from ._ufuncs import *
    641 
    642 from .basic import *

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Anyone know what happen? 
(I installed some other library such as tensorflow since the last time I use sklearn)

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: @asimo, I tried that but still got the error.

Comment: @seralouk, yeah. I reinstall anaconda then it works fine now.

Comment: @garjted  do you have more than one location where python is installed?

Comment: @asimo, I'm not sure, but I did have two anaconda before (one from visual studio, and the other I installed it myself), I thought that was the problem and I uninstalled the Visual Studio. Then it lead to a new error which I can't solve and I ended up reinstalling anaconda which solve all the problems I have.